# Pandas group by find the difference with respect to flag id's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I Have the following Data frame:

```
    id  flag  col_1  col_2  name
0   1   1      11    13      a
1   2   0      62    14      b 
2   1   0      13    15      a   
3   2   1      74    16      b  
4   3   1      25    17      c
5   3   0      22    18      c
```

I need this as the output -

```
    id  col_3  col_4  name
0   1     2       2     a
1   2   -12      -2     b 
2   3    -3       1     c
```

I need to group by id, name and take flag[0] of col_1 - flag[1] of the col_1 which has id, name in common.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using simple indexing with a temporary index ([`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html))

```
tmp = df.set_index(['flag', 'id', 'name'])

out = (tmp.loc[0] - tmp.loc[1]).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id name  col_1  col_2
0   1    a      2      2
1   2    b    -12     -2
2   3    c     -3      1
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3],
                   'flag': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'col_1': [11, 62, 13, 74, 25, 22],
                   'col_2': [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
                   'name': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c']})
```

Comment: Dataframe `tmp` cannot locate for the index 1, 0

Comment: @Vyshnavi I provided the reproducible input, please double check with that. Are you sure you always have 0/1? Are those numbers or strings?

Comment: They are strings. Worked ! but there are scenarios where we might not have flag either 0 or 1 for the specific names.

Comment: Then you can reindex `tmp` on the first level. But anyway here you wouldn't be able to compute the difference, right?

Comment: Yeah, We need to show Nan for the non existing flag scenarios

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution :

```
out = (
    df.groupby(["id", "name"])
        .apply(lambda g: -g.pop("flag").diff().max() * g.diff())
        .dropna().droplevel(2).reset_index()
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   id name  col_1  col_2
0   1    a   2.00   2.00
1   2    b -12.00  -2.00
2   3    c  -3.00   1.00
```

Comment: Hacky but smart one ;)

Comment: Thanks mozway ;) The last chains look awkward but I couldn't do better.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for reshape, so possible select `0/1` levels by `flag` column by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and subtract, last convert `Mulitindex in index` to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and get original order of columns by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) (with filter out `flag` column):

```
df1 = df.pivot(index=['id','name'], columns='flag')

out = (df1.xs(0, axis=1, level=1).sub(df1.xs(1, axis=1, level=1))
          .reset_index()
          .reindex(df.columns.difference(['flag'], sort=False), axis=1))
print (out)
   id  col_1  col_2 name
0   1      2      2    a
1   2    -12     -2    b
2   3     -3      1    c
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.groupby(['id', 'name'])[['flag', 'col_1', 'col_2']]
 .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('flag', ascending=False).diff())
 .dropna().droplevel(2).drop('flag', axis=1).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   id name  col_1  col_2
0   1    a    2.0    2.0
1   2    b  -12.0   -2.0
2   3    c   -3.0    1.0
```